# PHP CSV to Array if array contains "me" then else if

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am working on a php messenger project that reads up to 10 lines from a csv file into php as an array. 
I want to isolate the "me" messages from the "you" messages in the "From" column. I want to put each string in a different variable (less the "From" column) with up to 5 variables for me and 5 variables for "you" messages.

I am thinking I need to do a foreach loop through the array and "if" the array contains "me" in the From column then assign string to variable1 else if assign string to variable2 etc...

I am struggling to come up with method of foreach if on an array. 
sample data currently output from the code below

```
From    Time    Message
me  03/02/2020 13:34    test message 001
you 03/02/2020 13:34    test message 002
me  03/02/2020 13:34    test message 003
you 03/02/2020 13:34    test message 004
me  03/02/2020 13:34    test message 005
you 03/02/2020 13:34    test message 006
me  03/02/2020 13:34    test message 007
you 03/02/2020 13:34    test message 008
me  03/02/2020 13:34    test message 009
you 03/02/2020 13:34    test message 010
```

````
<?php

$filename = 'messenger.csv';
// Open the file for reading
$datadump  = [];

if (($h = fopen("{$filename}", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
  // Each line in the file is converted into an individual array that we call $$
  // The items of the array are comma separated
  while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
  {
    // Each individual array is being pushed into the nested array
  $datadump[] = $data;
  }

  // Close the file
  fclose($h);
}

// Display the code in a readable format

$build = '<table><thead><th>From</th><th>Time</th><th>Message</th></thead><tbody>;
foreach($datadump as $row)
{
$build .= '<tr>';
foreach($row as $item)
{
$build .= "<td>{$item}</td>";
}
$build .= '</tr>';
}
$build .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $build;
?>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check inside the `foreach` loop if the first index of the `$data` array is a message from **me** or **you** then assign the rest of the array to the corresponding resulting array (me or you). Try the code bellow:

```
$row = 1; // First line index
$me = []; // Me array;
$you = []; // You array

// Open the file for reading
if (($file = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    // Convert each line into the local $data variable
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        // To skip the file headers
        if ($row == 1) {
            $row++;
            continue;
        }

        // Change how you want to output the result
        $message = "Message: $data[2] at $data[1]";

        if($data[0] == "me") {
            $me[] = $message;
        } else if($data[0] == "you"){
            $you[] = $message;
        }
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose($file);
}

// Array of me
echo "<pre>";
print_r($me);
echo "<pre/>";

// Array of you
echo "<pre>";
print_r($you);
echo "<pre/>";
```

Edit:

```
$row = 1; // first line index
$messages = []; // messages array

// Open the file for reading
if (($file = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    // Convert each line into the local $data variable
    while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        // skip the file headers
        if ($row == 1) {
            $row++;
            continue;
        }

        $messages[] = [
            "sender"    => $data[0],
            "datetime"  => $data[1],
            "message"   => $data[2]
        ];
    }

    // Close the file
    fclose($file);
}

// Comparison function 
function date_compare($element1, $element2)
{
    $datetime1 = strtotime($element1['datetime']);
    $datetime2 = strtotime($element2['datetime']);
    return $datetime1 - $datetime2;
}

// Sort the array  
usort($messages, 'date_compare');
```

Then for the output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        th, td {
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2
        }

        th {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }
        .me {
            color: red;
        }
        .you {
            color: blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Message</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach ($messages as $message) { 
            $style = "class='me'";
            if($message["sender"] == "you") {
                $style = "class='you'";
            }
    ?>
        <tr <?php echo $style;?> >
            <td><?php echo $message["sender"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $message["datetime"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $message["message"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So this is a good start, however the output of each record must go into a separate variable. The "me" lines would go into numbered me1, me2 me3 etc variables and the "you" lines would go into you1, you 2 you3 etc numbered variables. (up to 5 each so we see the last 10 messages on the output)  those variables would be output in two different colors via css...and stacked just like text messaging on your phone.

Comment: Why do you need the variables for? the desired output can be build with the 2 arrays `$me` and `$you`

Comment: Honestly I was thinking to print the variables with the appropriate css....but printing the arrays might work however they need to be printed in order of received not all of the me's and then all of the you's.....might end up being 3 me lines then 2 you lines then 4 me lines then 1 you line.....this will mimic text messaging. The order will constantly change, just like text messaging on your phone.

Comment: I am going to edit my response. I think this is what you want.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you upvote the answer if it did help you. Thank you.

Comment: I did upvote but it gives me this message :  Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

- There seems to be an error when you pasted your code near `<tbody$`. You can fix it clicking `edit` below your post.
- What is the output you are trying to achieve?
- As a starting point, you might be looking after something like this:

```php
if (strpos($data, 'me') === 0) {
    // this line starts with "me"
} elseif (strpos($data, 'you') === 0) {
    // this line starts with "you"
} else {
    // this line starts with anything else
}
```

Comment: Corrected the error, thank you. The output will end up looking like sms messages on a phone. So I want to strip out the "me" and the "you" and represent those in different colors via css. Essentially I am trying to mimic text messaging.  I am assuming your if statement is used inside the while loop I already have?